# Use AssertJ to validate that list items are same value, but not same instance

Tags: java, testing, assertj

I'd like to know how to achieve the following using AssertJ:

I'm testing a function that clones the vertices of a graph and returns the cloned vertices as a list.  My test should confirm that the clones have the same value as the vertices, **and** that they are not the same instances.  I know how to achieve the first part.  It's the second part of that's got me stumped.

Comment: assertThat(result).isEqualTo(original).isNotSameAs(original)

Comment: @Arkadiy Thanks for the suggestion.  Would `isNotSameAs()` be applied to both the list and its contents?

Comment: no... More research required :)

Comment: :) got it.  Thanks.  I think doing this may allow for a false negative: when the list is the same instance, but the items it contains are not.  Whereas I'm not interested in the instance of the list container - I'm only interested in that of the contents.

Comment: `doesNotContainAnyElementsOf` ? May use equals though

Comment: Yeah, I considered that.  But the contents of the list are value objects - this allows equals to return true when two objects have the same state but are separate instances.  Based on the docs, my expectation was that `doesNotContainAnyElementsOf` would return false because both lists would be compared by value and thus found to contain the same items.

Comment: My ideal method would be something like `doesNotContainAnyInstancesIn(otherList)` - which doesn't exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158455/discussion-between-arkadiy-and-julian).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a specific comparator for collections assertions:

```
assertThat(clonedVertices).usingElementComparator(referenceComparator)
                          .doesNotContainAnyElementsOf(originalVertices);
```

where `referenceComparator` only compares well ... references.

See http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#custom-comparison-strategy

Hope it helps